# Multiple drag and drop using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to make multiple drag and drop items through different blocks  using jQuery UI.
The problem is that I don't know how to show the items in the input bar below for what I've dragged to 'Second Articles', it only works when I dragged items to the First Articles.

Actually, I don't know how to put `updateAdd()` into line31, or should I write another function to do this?
[image]

Sorry, I'm not sure is it clear of the problem because my English isn't good. Check the code on Codepen then you might know what I'm talking about: https://codepen.io/anniesnoopymd/pen/brKdGM?editors=1010

Any ideas are highly appreciated! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `update` event to an anonymous function, calling `updatePostOrder()` and `updateAdd()`:

```
update: function(){
            updatePostOrder();
            updateAdd();
        }
```

You can then eliminate those calls at the end of your main function.

In total:

```
$(function () {
    $('.droptrue').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
       ...
        },
        start: function (e, ui) {
            ...
        },
        receive: function (e, ui) {
           ...
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            ...
        },
        update: function(){
            updatePostOrder();
            updateAdd();
        }
    });
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").css('minHeight', $("#sortable1, #sortable2").height() + "px");
});
```

See this forked Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjrpgX?editors=1010